# Java Simple Serial Connector (jssc) no ports detected

Tags: java

I'm using jSSC-2.6.0 in a cross-platform application. The returned portlist on Windows machines (32/64bit) are correct, however the MacOSX (v10.6 and 10.7) application does not return any serial devices. If I view the serial devices manually in terminal `ls /dev/tty.*`, I can view three devices. Running the following line from the jssc example file returns nothing on that same MAC machine:

`String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();`

I can only see a whole bunch of devices, including the ones in the terminal, after I use:

`String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames("/dev/", Pattern.compile("tty."));`

A drawback is that it hangs the machine for 10 seconds and on the other machine (10.7) it does not respond after 30 seconds.

Is there a way to reliably connect to a serial device on the MAC using jssc?

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://pbxbook.com/other/mac-tty.html

Comment: Unfortunately we are already using the MCP2200 as our USB<->Serial device

Answer (score 3):

jSSC use this `regexp` for listing serial ports on Mac: `tty.(serial|usbserial|usbmodem).*` If your device cannot be found with this regexp you should change it for getting your device name.

The next important thing is that jSSC try to open port and get `termios` structure for identify the real serial device. In described situation I can suggest to use only official and latests drivers. Port listing functionality is realy simple, try to use some serial port terminal for checking this issue on another software.

Comment: upvote: "A drawback is that it hangs the machine for 10 seconds and on the other machine (10.7)" -> " In described situation I can suggest to use only official and latests drivers."